# Attach a callback on click of a button which does an ajax operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, .when

I'm aware that this can be achieved via a Promise but I am struggling to figure out how.

```
jQuery('.parentDiv').on('click', '.link', function(e) {
  jQuery.when(jQuery('.saveBtn').trigger('click', { 'evtData': 'link' })).then(function {
    // rest of the logic that should be performed on click of .link
  }); 
});
```

The click of `.saveBtn` calls a function named `doAjax`:

```
jQuery('.saveBtn').on('click', function() {
  doAjax()
});

function doAjax() {
  var ajaxCall = jQuery.ajax(ajaxObject);
  ajaxCall.done(function(data, status, xhr) {
    //some logic go here
  });
  return ajaxCall;
}
```

Despite this the logic inside the `.then` handler is getting executed first i.e before `doAjax` completes.

I believe I need to change the `jQuery.when(jQuery('.saveBtn').trigger('click',{'evtData':'link'}))` as it may not be getting the Promise state which it should and immediately getting marked as Resolved thereby executing the callback without waiting?.
I tried return doAjax in .saveBtn but that also did not make a difference.

Ideas please.

Comment: Yes I had thought of that but there is a lot of logic happening on click of Save which also is needed to be done on click of link,Isnt there a way to make the trigger a promise in someway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `trigger()` is not an async function, so `then` is called immediately. It would make far more sense to just call `doAjax()` directly from the click of `.link` instead of faking DOM events. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.parentDiv').on('click', '.link', function(e) {
    doAjax().then(function {
      // rest of the logic that should be performed on click of .link
    });
  });

  $('.saveBtn').on('click', function() {
    doAjax()
  });

  function doAjax() {
    var ajaxCall = $.ajax(ajaxObject);
    ajaxCall.done(function(data, status, xhr) {
      // some logic go here
    });
    return ajaxCall;
  }
});
```

Comment: I have shortened these event handlers in the question alot for simplicity but lot of logic is there in each of the handler.

Comment: Ok, is there a reason the amount of logic in the functions affects anything? The pattern you need to follow is still the same.

Comment: I was thinking if `return doAjax()` inside the `.saveBtn` could do this? or maybe using `triggerHandler` instead?

Comment: No, you can't return anything from an event handler.